# How to test two objects in xunit using FluentAssertions

Tags: c#, unit-testing, fluent-assertions

I have a Matrix class, and another class which is using that matrix changing it a little bit. I'd like to test both matrix, one from the matrix class and the other one which has been changed, so I can confirmed they're not the same.

Something like this.

```
[Fact]
public void MatrixFromMatrixIsntTheSameThanMatrixFromMineSweeper()
{
    Matrix _matrix = new Matrix(4, 4);
    MineSweeper mineSweeper = new MineSweeper(4, 4, 2);

    mineSweeper.Matrix.Should().NotBe(_matrix);
}
```

The thing is that `Be/NotBe` seems is using the reference from the object, so always it returns false because they're not the same. I also have tried with `NotBeSameAs`, `NotBeEquivalentTo`.

These are the Matrix and MineSweeper class.

### Matrix Class

```
public struct Coordinate
{
    public int X;
    public int Y;

    public Coordinate(int x, int y)
        => (X, Y) = (x, y);
}

public class Matrix
{
    private readonly int _M, _N;
    private readonly Cell[,] _matrix;
    private const char InitValue = '.';

    public Matrix(int m,  int n)
    {
        (_M, _N) = (m, n);
        _matrix = new Cell[m, n];
        Initialize();
    }

    private void Initialize()
    { 
        for (int m = 0; m < _M; m++)
            for (int n = 0; n < _N; n++)
                _matrix[m, n] = new Cell(InitValue);
    }

    public Cell At(Coordinate coordinate) 
        => _matrix[coordinate.X, coordinate.Y];
    
    public void SetMine(Coordinate coordinate)
    { 
        _matrix[coordinate.X, coordinate.Y] = new Cell('*');
    }
}
```

### MineSweeper Class

```
public class MineSweeper
{
    private readonly int _m, _n, _numMines;
    public Matrix Matrix { get; }

    public MineSweeper(int m, int n, int numMines)
    {
        (_m, _n, _numMines) = (m, n, numMines);
        Matrix = new Matrix(m, n);
        SetMines();
    }

    private void SetMines()
    {
        HashSet<Coordinate> minesSet = new HashSet<Coordinate>();
        Random rnd = new Random();

        while (minesSet.Count != _numMines)
            minesSet.Add(new Coordinate(rnd.Next(0, _m), rnd.Next(0, _n)));

        foreach (Coordinate coordinate in minesSet)
            Matrix.SetMine(coordinate);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your usage of tuples, you're using a recent .NET version. This gives you access to [`record`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/record), which I recommend you use for your `Cell` structure.

```
public record struct Cell (char Value);
```

Records come with an implied constructor and equality comparison. The equality comparison is important for you, because to compare two `Matrix` objects, you would need to make sure the content of their `Cell[,]` are identical.

You now have two options:

### 1. Should().Equal()

Works on `IEnumerable`. So if you want to compare two `Matrix` objects, you want to expose the contents of your `Cell[,]` arrays and compare the two. You use `Equal()` because you want to compare the order of items. Don't use `BeEquivalentTo()` because it doesn't care about order. [See here for the different enumerable comparisons](https://fluentassertions.com/collections/).

```
public class Matrix {
  ...
  // Expose your array as an IEnumerable
  public IEnumerable<Cell> Cells => _matrix.OfType<Cell>();
}

// And compare the contents in sequence
public void Test(){
    // These have 1 Mine in the same location:
    Matrix m1 = new(4,4); m1.SetMine(new(1,1));
    Matrix m2 = new(4,4); m2.SetMine(new(1,1));
    // 1 Mine in a different location:
    Matrix xx = new(4,4); xx.SetMine(new(2,2));

    // Same contents in the same order
    m2.Cells.Should().Equal(m1.Cells);
    // Same contents different order, are NOT Equal
    xx.Cells.Should().NotEqual(m1.Cells);
    // But are Equivalent
    xx.Cells.Should().BeEquivalentTo(m1.Cells);

}
```

### 2. Should().Be()

If you want to be strict with encapsulation, and don't want to expose the contents of your `Cell[,]` as public, then you're going to have to define your equality comparison between 2 `Matrix` objects. This allows you to use `Be()` which will call the object's `Equals()` method.

([Here's a full fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0iYCRF) of the code below)

```
public class Matrix {
    ...
    /* Easiest way to compare two Cell collections is to join
       the chars into a string, and perform string comparison.
       
       We could go through the two arrays and compare the contents 
       one by one, but a good programmer is a lazy one.
    */
    private string CellsAsString() // private so the public can't see it
        => string.Concat(_matrix.OfType<Cell>().Select(c => c.Value));

    /* Now Override the Equality comparison of the Object */
    public override bool Equals(object other)
        => this.CellsAsString().Equals((other as Matrix)?.CellsAsString());
    // Note that we can access private methods of another object
    // as long as it's the same class as `this`.

}
```

Your comparison will now simply be:

```
Matrix m1 = new(4,4); m1.SetMine(new(1,1));
Matrix m2 = new(4,4); m2.SetMine(new(1,1));
Matrix xx = new(4,4); xx.SetMine(new(2, 2));

m2.Should().Be(m1);
xx.Should().NotBe(m1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally we recommend `BeEquivalentTo`, but since your `Matrix` class doesn't expose any public fields or properties, the only other option is what [NPras](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5623232/npras) suggested in option 2.